# What gauge wire is needed to feed a 100A subpanel that's next to the main panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

The subpanel will be just a few inches from the main panel. Looks like more or less 3 feet of cable  will be used. How thick should the copper conductors be?

Comment: Aluminum still makes more sense, even though you can afford 3 feet of vastly overpriced copper...and cable is not the best choice - panels right next to each other implies conduit implies THHN or XHHW wires as a better choice

Comment: Also, the lugs you'll be attaching to are made of aluminum. As are the bus bars on most panels.  Note that the most valuable parameter of a subpanel is number of spaces, spaces are very cheap at panel buying time, and wishing you had gotten more spaces is very expensive. You can have 30-40 breakers in a 100A subpanel.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by a [wire ampacity chart](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/), you have a couple options:

- #3 copper THW/THWN/XHHW/etc. at 75C
- #1 aluminum THW/THWN/XHHW/etc. at 75C

Seriously consider aluminum. There is no safety problem with aluminum wires on the aluminum lugs that will be involved at all the terminations. The price difference is significant, even at short lengths. It's about a factor of four: on the order of $2 per foot per conductor for copper vs. $0.50 per foot per conductor for aluminum at these sizes.

Three feet sounds optimistic unless the panels happen to line up perfectly - you might need an extra foot or two for bending length, plus some extra to guarantee against having it end up too short due to mis-estimating.

This assumes you are connecting the two panels with a short conduit fitting, as individual wires must be in conduit, not out in the open (even for very short distances like a few inches).

If you absolutely cannot fit conduit, you'll have to use a cable, such as NM-B. That'd be #2 copper at 60C, around $20/foot. In aluminum, you can find 1/0 SER (bigger than strictly necessary) for more like $2/foot.

Whatever you use, don't forget to properly torque all connections.

Comment: For a panel-to-panel jumper, you won't ever use the 90degC numbers

Comment: The terninals are not rated for 90°C, so ***sizing based on 90°C is an error.*** Most terminals on breakers/panels **are** rated for 75°C. The 90°C numbers are used for derate calculations when those are required.